# Query Coinbase Pro Stablcoin Conversion History

Tags: coinbase-api, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to reconstruct a Coinbase Pro account's history, which includes stablecoin conversions. I see that [there's an API endpoint](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#stablecoin-conversions) to *effect* such conversions, but what about querying conversions already done?! Neither [deposits](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#deposits) nor [withdrawals](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#list-withdrawals) (including internal ones) appear to include this.

Am I missing something or does the API really not cover this?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you're looking for is for [ledgers](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getaccountledger). You can use that to recreate all account history. Incidentally, I just added fetchLedger to coinbasepro in [CCXT](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) the other day to help me accomplish this task.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the API documentation has changed since my post (as my links now look dead). This does indeed look responsive, but does it apply to both Coinbase and CoinbasePro / Prime?